# How to programmatically navigate to another page in Blazor 8 RC2 static mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Blazor in .NET 8 introduces the option to execute on the server (so called static mode). It can accept Form POSTs which is great. But how am I supposed to navigate to another page after that? If I call NavigationManager.NavigatoTo I get Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException

Is there any other way to redirect the user to another page?

Some example code

```
namespace DemoBlazorWebApp.Client.Pages;

using DemoBlazorWebApp.Dtos;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

public partial class ProductCreate
{
    [Inject]
    private NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; } = null!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private ProductCreateDto Model { get; set; } = new();
    private bool IsSaving { get; set; }

    private async Task SubmitAsync()
    {
        IsSaving = true;

        try
        {
            ProductDto? product = await //save the product somehow

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Products/" + product.ProductId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            IsSaving = false;
        }
    }
}

@page "/Products/Create"

<h3>Product Create</h3>

@if (IsSaving)
{

    <p>
        Saving...
    </p>
}
else
{
    <EditForm FormName="ProductCreate" Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="SubmitAsync">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />
        <p>
            <label>
                
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                Name:
                <InputText @bind-Value="Model.Name" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                Price:
                <InputNumber @bind-Value="Model.Price"></InputNumber>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>
                Description:
                <InputTextArea @bind-Value="Model.Description" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </EditForm>
}
```

Note that the Routes that host the page should be in the new default static mode (i.e. no other RenderMode specified) and one should be using the new web app script

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @MarvinKlein I did, although I really would have to share the whole project because the interactivity mode cascades down and it is important that the Routes component do not have an Interactivity mode set

Comment: Let me guess, you have chosen the static template option with interactive per page/component and enabled InteractiveServer for the component or page, right?

Comment: @MarvinKlein no... in the real code I had try/catch around the saving part that I deleted in the example above :( Turns out the navigation works by throwing an exception and I caught it... I've now added the try/catch in the example code and I am waiting for the answer to be edited so I can accept it. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing and reviewing comments, we iterated to the conclusion that the issue lays within the `try{} catch{}` blocks.

So, removing the `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Products/" + product.ProductId);` line from the `try{}` block made the difference.

Catching the exception (that is no harmful anyway) "eats" the navigation. Honestly I don't understand why it works like that. There are similar issues with pre-rendering and navigating within `OnInitializedAsync`, but nothing about .NET 8. I am embarked on a mission to unravel this behavior and will circle back with insights.

Comment: This is correct but I don't want to use Blazor Server (which now is called InteractiveServer), I do want to use the Razor Pages-like functionality. I simply want to redirect after receiving the data from the form and saving it to the DB.

Comment: Ah, understand now...I have created minimal sample and it is working for me, check the answer and let me know.

Comment: Wow... stupid me. I shortened the code a bit. I had try/catch around the code that I decided to remove for the example. Apparently the NavigateTo works by throwing exception. I was catching it and then when I looked at it in the debugger I thought something went wrong but this was how it was supposed to work. I will update my sample code with the try catch. Please update your answer (probably remove that old answer part) to say that NavigateTo works by throwing exception

Comment: The behavior has some logic in it. It is reasonable for a dev to want the execution of the current method to end when a navigation is requested similar to a return but the return type of the method doesn't match so they need to throw exception. Interestingly that was how Web Forms used to do navigation but they used very special ThreadAbortException that had weird behavior with catch (you catch it but at the end of the block it is rethrown regardless of the code you wrote)